# HTML: Do screen readers read inline-block elements separately even if there is no space between them?

Tags: html, screen-readers

I can't seem to find any information on this, but maybe someone here would know. Do screen readers read inline-block elements separately even if there is no space between them? For example:

```
<head><style>
div {
    display: inline-block;
}
</style></head>

<div>Hello</div><div>World</div>
```

Will this get read as one word, "HelloWorld" (because there's no space between the elements) or as two, "Hello World" (because they are separate elements)? Does it depend on the screen reader, or do they typically behave all the same way (as far as this is concerned)? When I *look* at the page in the browser, obviously it looks like "HelloWorld" but I don't know if screen readers go by that. `inline` elements I would expect to be read as one word. `inline-block` elements I don't know.

I'm asking because I have an `inline-block` layout. Listing the elements without the spaces would make it easier to calculate their positions and so forth, but I don't want to do it if it comes at the expense of screen readers accessibility. Plus, I don't know what the conditions are (does it only matter if the element is a `div` as opposed to a `span` and it doesn't care what the CSS sets the display to? etc.).

Thanks for any help. If there's any documentation on this somewhere, that would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will be "HelloWorld" Because `inline-block` elements doesn't take the whole width of the block, it's just the same size as the contents and no space after.
So, If you made 2 `<div>`s , and `.div` has `Display:inline-block` in CSS
they will be put one after another in order without spaces.
If you need spaces, Specify an `ID` for each `<div>`, play with the position of each `<div>` using it's `ID` in CSS.